# HTTP 406 Error Occured Upgrade to Spring MVC 4.1 Using JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

After upgrade to Spring MVC 4.1.1, when I using JSON, it will occur HTTP 406 error.

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- JSON Support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

**Controller.java**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Boolean> loginAction(
        @RequestParam(value="username", required=true) String username,
        @RequestParam(value="password", required=true) String password,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session,
        Model model) {
    String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    HashMap<String, Boolean> result = getLoginResult(username, password);
    logger.info(String.format("User: [Username=%s] tried to log in at %s", new Object[] {username, ipAddress}));
    if ( result.get("isSuccessful") ) {
        getSession(request, session, this.user);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doLoginAction(username, password) {
        var postData = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<c:url value="/accounts/login.action" />',
                data: postData,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    return processLoginResult(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The log message will output to the console normally.
And the code works fine in Spring MVC 4.0.5.

Do you know how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading Jackson's version should fix this issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

See the [Spring migration wiki on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#libraries).

Comment: You mean remove *org.codehaus.jackson* dependency and add *com.fasterxml.jackson.core*? This not working on my machine. It throws model class not found exception.

Comment: I still think that the first step to solve this problem is updating the dependency. You probably need to update import statements in your application. Otherwise you can update your question and add a full stacktrace there.